# Streaming music between 2 computers via Bluetooth

Tags: networking, bluetooth, speakers

In my warehouse, we use multiple computers with multiple sets of speakers. It gets noisy between multiple sets of speakers playing different music. Now, i have the computers linked with Bluetooth and can send/receive files with out a problem. I have searched and searched *and searched* for a program to be able to stream music between computers and essentially have one massive set of speakers.

Is this even possible?
Thank you

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. That thread helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows PC, Voicemeeter Banana will help you to manage several speaker systems and send/receive audio on different devices of your local network (LAN or WLAN) thanks to VBAN protocol (with a better latency than with bluetooth) www.voicemeeter.com